# Electron-builder desktop shortcut icon has to be enabled manually

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

When I create and install an executable using Electron-Builder, the desktop shortcut instead displays an Electron icon. I have to manually `Change Icon...` for `icon.ico` to take effect.

```
"target": "nsis",
"icon": "assets/icon_256.ico",
"nsis": {
  "installerIcon": "assets/icon.ico",
  "uninstallerIcon": "assets/icon.ico",
  "installerHeaderIcon": "assets/icon.ico"
}

// I have also tried this, which also produces the same issue.

"win": {
  "target": "nsis",
  "icon": "assets/icon_256.ico"
}
```

Is there a way to force it to take effect upon installation as would be expected?

[image]

Link to the issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/4662).

Comment: Look like icon configuration is not set properly. For example in our `electron-builder.yml` this is how we are setting icon for our app: `win:
  target:
    target: nsis
  icon: public/icons/icon.png`

Comment: @Asesh can u submit an answer with a properly structured example. having a hard time understanding the example u provided in that format

Comment: @Asesh im not using a `yml` file, but rather changing the `package.json` as suggested in the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Here some tips you can try:
1.Be sure you are using real .ico file，not just rename file extension, But use some tool to transform.
2.try replace "assets/icon_256.ico" with "./assets/icon_256.ico". And check your file path

Comment: thank you. i will try this the next time i build an electron app if i run into the same problem!